# How "strong" is a password generated using PostgreSQL `random()`?

Tags: passwords

I need to generate password on row creation in PostgreSQL. I have solution like this:

```
ALTER TABLE sippeers ALTER secret    
SET DEFAULT trim(both from (encode(decode(md5(random()::text || current_timestamp || random()),'hex'),'base64')), '=');
```

And passwords look like this:

```
select trim(both from (encode(decode(md5(random()::text || current_timestamp || random()),'hex'),'base64')), '=') FROM generate_series(1,15);
         btrim          
------------------------
 MVve5ziDWUweBcNHpZU0zA
 ERPkHr407VvQUoxLNmsg9A
 zi6+zYGTFl5EqxvQTuIfsw
 vXJRb2RJzaikQDXCWYWKFg
 LHfAYJkrFJzKGRR1mAyeqA
 +JQIcr+CkYsFDH6HaGQTeQ
 gEeZjD/6zI5btzRfaKebYw
 Qi7jyLadnQ3FXBYLhU2TaQ
 DR70MoyHHyLHlUmBCj9Lzg
 87gaalFYGgs76N02/CLfLw
 93407RcVXT5+ei9KeuejXA
 C5iONK9ef4jHFrj1oNrxSQ
 +JZaWNtjRFUbdMCGIxdQgw
 3AOUzdeqIL2qS2YfAXSDhg
 +giwgzxkEa6gvman4Ccujw
(15 wierszy)
```

I know `random()` in not really random. Cannot use pgcrypto.

How "strong" passwords generated like this will be?

Comment: Why would you generate/verify passwords on the database server instead of the application?

Comment: This table is needed only for Asterisk VoIP PBX Realtime configuration and row will be created on insert trigger. This will allow integration with another system without changing its source code. This will be temporary solution for testing LTE VoIP call quality before source code change.

Comment: See also [Quality of PostgreSQL's random() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816114/quality-of-postgresqls-random-function)

Comment: it's downright terrible. certainly not the worst ever, but far from satisfactory for cryptographic purposes. adding a predictable timestamp makes it even worse. use a CSPRNG or just raw pulls from `/urandom/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816114/quality-of-postgresqls-random-function), PostgreSQL's random is a 48-bit LCG. This means it has 48 bit seed and 48 bit state. Once somebody guesses either of those, he can generate the same numbers as you, so also the same passwords.

As far as I can tell, in PostgreSQL the seed is always the same (unless you call setseed). This means that an attacker can create a list of passwords by just running the same function you used to create the passwords. He can then use this list to brute-force your application.

If an attacker obtains one of the passwords, he can deduce all other passwords, even if you seed the random function correctly.

Comment: Even when using `current_timestamp`? `(random()::text || current_timestamp || random())`

Answer (score 1):

The real answer will depend on the level of security you need for your system. As you rightly point out this function does not carry the entropy that a good cryptographically sound pseudorandom function does. But as I say this may be 'good enough' for your scenario only you will know.

As a side note I've always worked with systems where by the application handles the mangemengt of passwords, I guess there is a reason you are doing them at the database layer

Comment: Just to add... all of us know now ;)